# jQuery not working in PHP include

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I got a little problem with jQuery here.

Basically, I include my pages in the index.php page. However, SOME jQuery is not working, while others are okay. All scripts used in all pages are loaded in the  tag of index.php.

```
      <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Shy Shop</title>
      <!--js-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/common.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ddsmoothmenu.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.elastislide.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.accordion.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/light_box.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/search.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});});
      </script>
      <!--end js-->

      <!-- Mobile Specific Metas ================================================== -->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

      <!-- CSS ================================================== -->
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/icons/favicon.png">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colors.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ddsmoothmenu.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/elastislide.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home_flexslider.css"/>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/light_box.css"/>
      <link href="../../../html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">

      <!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->

      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                  <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
              <![endif]-->

      </head>
```

And this is how I include the rest of the files in index.php.

```
          <?php
          if(!isset($_REQUEST['pg']))
          {
              $pg = "home";
          }
          else
              $pg = $_REQUEST['pg'];
          if($pg=="shopguide")
              include("faqs.php");
          elseif($pg=="aboutus")
              include("aboutus.php");
          elseif($pg=="contactus")
              include("contactus.php");
          elseif($pg=="home")
              include("home.php");
          elseif($pg=="shop")
              include("shop.php");
          elseif($pg=="sitemap")
              include("sitemap.php");
          elseif($pg=="product")
              include("product.php");
          elseif($pg=="shoppingcart")
              include("shoppingcart.php");
          elseif($pg=="profile")
              include("account.php");
          elseif($pg=="orders")
              include("orders.php");
          elseif($pg=="wishlist")
              include("mywishlist.php");
          elseif($pg=="changepassword")
              include("changepassword.php");
          elseif($pg=="newmessage")
              include("newmessage.php");
          elseif($pg=="receivedmessages")
              include("receivedmessages.php");
          elseif($pg=="ordersummary")
              include("ordersummary.php");
          elseif($pg=="test")
              include("test.php");
          elseif($pg=="viewmessage")
              include("viewmessage.php");
          elseif($pg=="register")
              include("register.php");
          elseif($pg=="login")
              include("login.php");
          elseif($pg=="reseller")
              include("reseller.php");
          elseif($pg=="myaccount")
              include("orders.php");
        ?>
```

An example of a working js in the included files is the jcarousel.min.js.
The accordion.js and light_box.js does not work with the included files, but they work when they are used in a single file.

Console says: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

Comment: Just a suggestion: use an associative array to determine which page to `include`. `$pages = array('shopguide' => 'faqs.php', 'aboutus' => 'aboutus.php')`, etc.

Comment: in console click on the error, it will take you to exact line of crime. Even you could look at right most part of error for the line number

Comment: This is probably a file path issue. Ensure you are stating the correct path from the included directory.

Comment: @Vector I copy-pasted the same links from the previous file.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh it points to this.

<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$(function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion();
});
});
</script>

Comment: This issue may happen when you have same plugin/jquery files included in other php files too. e.g. in index.php, you have some JS files, you are including other PHP files which may also have same JS again. In such cases, jQuery behaves like this. To check this, just check the view source of generated html.

Comment: @ApulGupta Thank you. I did as you said. The files are included just once.

Answer (score 0):

> This issue may happen when you have same plugin/jquery files included
>   in other php files too. e.g. in index.php, you have some JS files, you
>   are including other PHP files which may also have same JS again. In
>   such cases, jQuery behaves like this. To check this, just check the
>   view source of generated html.

Comment: Thank you. I did as you said. The files are included just once, and still not working.